# What exactly does it means the Argument in the always @ ( ) expression in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, synthesis

When I have a sensitivity expression like this:

```
always @ (data)
begin
.
.
end
```

does it means that every time "data" change the "begin" process will occur? But what happen if the data actually change to a same number, for instance: reading a list of finite numbers (where value of data sometimes is the same than its contiguous). In this case, would it recognize it as a new data (even though is the same value) or would it just ignore it as a "change" and "begin" won't activate itself?

Answer (score 4):

`always@` blocks are used to **describe events** that should happen under **certain conditions**.

`always@( * )` blocks are used to describe **Combinational Logic, or Logic Gates**.

`always@(posedge Clock)` (“always at the **positive edge of the clock**”) or `always@(negedge Clock)` (“always at the **negative edge of the clock**”) blocks are used to describe **Sequential Logic, or Registers**.

The **sensitivity list** specifies which signals should **trigger the elements inside** the `always` block. The following are some examples:

```
always @ ( A or B ) begin // executes when A=1 or B=1
// always @ ( * )   begin // same as above. executes when A=1 or B=1
 C = A & B ;
end

always @ ( A and B ) begin // executes when A=1 AND B=1
 C = A & B ;
end
```

**Incomplete sensitivity lists** are almost **NEVER desired**. They introduce very hard-to-find **bugs**. As such, we use `always@(*)`.  ‘*’ **sets** the **sensitivity** list to **any values** that can have an **impact on a value(s) determined** by the `always@(*)` block.

In your case, if `data` remains the **same**, then `always` block **will never be executed**. In your case too, if it is a combinational block, `always@(*)` is **recommended**.

If the `data` remains the **same at every time stamp**, then the given `always` block **shall not** be executed. Since the **inputs/sensitivity elements** (`@(data)`) have remained **same** and **outputs/computed elements** (**logic value computation** inside `always` block) which are computed  should also be **same**.

For somewhat more details, [Always block PDF](http://www.eet.bme.hu/~nagyg/mikroelektronika/Always.pdf) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You are right.
Suppose data change on every clock, and data_delayed is flopped version of data, then 
`begin...end` is executed only when 
`data_delayed != data`, so if data change to same value it won't be executed.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are only relevant from an RTL synthesis point of view. For higher levels of synthesis, or from a non-synthesis point of view, it think this is a clear description:

An `always` construct instantiates a single process that begins at time 0 of a simulation and exists for all time after that.  That process may consist of a single procedural statement, or a block of procedural statements. When the procedural statement or statements complete, the process starts the procedural statements over again.

Now, any procedural statement can have a timing control in front of it, like `@(expression)` or `#(delay)`. The `@(expression)` means wait for a change in the value of the expression. The change has to come **after** executing the statement having the timing control. This is why

```
always @(data) statement;
```

does not become an infinite loop.

The reason why the above should **not** be read as *"every time data changes, execute statement"* is because if that statement blocked for some about of time while data changed again, the statement does not get executed until after it has completed. For example

```
always @(posedge clk) do_this;

task do_this;
  // some stuff
  @(posedge clk);
  // some more stuff
endtask
```

The do_this task does not get called every @(posedge clk). It gets called every other @(posedge clk).

It possible to have

```
always @(data) statement;
```

execute more than once in the same slot, but that depends on both how data changes its value as well as what the statement is, bit I'll leave that for a more advanced discussion.

Comment: So what I understood from your answer is,  always @ (data) begin . . . end doesn't execute until and unless the operation inside the begin. . . end is executed? Am I Right ? @dave_59